# Why is my c sharp command prompt code not working on my server but working fine on my local pc

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I created some code to execute a command line command. It is working fine on my development PC but when I try to run the code on the server (Windows 2003, IIS 6) the command does not run.

I check the path on the server and I am sure it is correct. I am able to get some output from the server (see the attached image).

[image: server output image]

I am thinking this might be a permissions issue. But I am not sure where to check this and how to correct it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I am running this code on my local development PCs (Win 7 and Wind XP)  and it is working fine. But as soon as I run the code on my Windows 2003 server it does not work.

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

if (process != null)
{
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("c:");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd\\");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\Program Files\\Bank2CSV Pro");

/*This is Dynamic path for our application */

process.StandardInput.WriteLine("bank2csv_pro.exe" + " " + strSavedFilePath + fileName2    + " " + strSavedFilePath + fileNameCsv);

/* This is static path for command prompt*/

process.StandardInput.Close();
string outputString = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  If you run that code *on your server* then the best that will happen is that an instance of IE will launch *on your server* and no user will be able to interact with it.  I can't imagine that's your required functionality.

Comment: I am actually going to run a utility that converts banking files to csv and present that to the user. I have it fully working in my development environment. I thought to simplify matters for testing reasons on the server, I should use the line of code that opens the browser. It is just so that I am sure the command is executing....

Comment: But, on the server, you probably don't have IIS running in an interactive session, so that session can't launch a window anyway.  You're not going to present anything back to the user with that command line on the server...

Comment: Yes Dan, that is correct. I am just trying to execute a simple command on the server to get things working. I did not include the code retuning data to the user. Currently I am unable to execute the simplest command line code on the server. This is what I am trying to solve. My problem is the command line code in c sharp is not executing on the server.

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to execute something on the server that can't run on the server!  I'd suggest you stop trying to launch IE from a non-interactive process, and do something that you *can* do, like writing your output to disc or displaying status in a page that you're rendering.

Comment: the code on your server isn't running under "the user you're logged in as" or even " the user you're browsing as."  It's running under "the user that IIS is running as."  That user is a service account, which doesn't typically have permission to run interactive processes (that is, processes that launch a window or other UI) and, further, isn't properly "logged in" to the PC as you would typically understand that.  Because of that, your code *cannot launch* an instance of IE when run on the server, and there is no sensible way around that.

Comment: thank you Dan. I will take your advice and test with something more sensible i.e. stop using IE as a test. writing a file to disk is closer to that I really want to achieve. I will try that now

Comment: Dan, the one thing that is slightly confusing is that when I use the same code on my development system. I am able to launch IE with my code. I presume this difference is that windows server does not work the same as windows 7 and that is why I am not able to launch IE on the server?

Comment: When you run code on your development system I'd imagine you're running either Cassini, IIS Express, or a version of IIS that runs under your own user account.  You're also logged in to the system as the user that IIS is running as.  If you were to run your code on your machine under IIS without logging in, you'd see exactly the same problem.

Comment: Do you know how I can get round this problem? I mean how would you run the code as a user that has the correct rights to execute the command? We are using IIS 6 on the development server

Comment: You shouldn't do this.  It's a server, not a client machine. Launching IE on the server is not a sensible thing to do.

Comment: Dan, please see the update that I made on the question. I am not trying to run IE on the server. I am however trying to run a utility. Please see the code snippet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been testing and found that I was able to execute the code as shown in the code snippet above when working in the web root directory of the web server.

So in the end it seems it was a permissions problem. To give a practical example of what I did

I modified the code from this:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\Program Files\\Bank2CSV Pro");
```

to this code:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\Bank2CSV Pro");
```

After this change I was able to execute commands that write to disk. Clearly the problem was that the IUSR user has to have permission to write to the directory in question. I could also solve the problem by giving the ISUR user disk write access to the folder in the Program Files directory, but I think this is not good practice...

Comment: i m running SVN cmd commands.so at place of `process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin");`
i have place `process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\SlikSvn\bin");`
if yes then i have to copy slikSvn folder from program files to wwwroot folder?